# Custom Admin module: empty POST on create, not on edit

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, adminform

I created a custom admin module.

On create, there is only the *form_key* in the post. So it saves an empty line in my database.

On edit save, everything is fine...

Anyone has a hint ?

Comment: Please, update your question with the code lines.

Comment: I did not post any code because i would to post the entire module... I'm using UiComponent form. I bet it's a Knockout JS that do not post the correct datas... I was just wondering if anyone encountered the same pb having no data posted on create model, but empty entry created in database, but everything OK on edit.